# FireMonkey Dialog Not Full Screen

Tags: android, c++, modal-dialog, firemonkey

I am writing a progress dialog in C++ Builder 10.4 with FireMonkey.

I want the dialog to be centered in the selected screen.

In Windows 32/64, my dialog shows / works fine using the ShowModal() using anonymous functions.

The problem is in Android my progress dialog shows in full screen no matter what I set the Bounds to.

Is there a flag in the Android Manifest I need to set or is there a simple method to keep my code common to all platforms?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a mobile version of my progress dialog using a technique of another programmer; that is, I take a screen shot of the calling (parent) form, display it on my progress form's background, and use a panel for my actual progress dialog controls.

Hope that rambling makes sense and helps someone else.

All the best,

Aggie85